# python lib for custom hash function

Tags: python

I need a hash function to take a sequence of decimal numbers and return a decimal number as hash value.

for example:

```
>> def my_simple_hash(*args):
    return reduce(lambda x1, x2: 2*x1 + x2,  args) 

>>> my_simple_hash(1,3,4)
14
>>> my_simple_hash(1,4,3)
15
>>> my_simple_hash(4,3,1)
23
```

My questions are:

1. does python has a built-in lib to do this more efficiently?
2. how could I make the output hash value in a relative small range?

Question 2 explanation:

because 1, 3, 4 has six different combinations as following:

```
1,3,4
1,4,3
3,1,4
3,4,1
4,1,3
4,3,1
```

the corresponding output is `[14, 15, 18, 21, 21, 23]`, and I expect the hash values of the `six` output would be something like `[1,2,3,4,6]`(a small range)

any suggestions would be appreciated. 
thanks in advance :-)

Comment: I would generally advise not to roll your own, and instead go with a hash that’s virtually guaranteed not to have collisions (`hashlib.sha256()`).

Comment: That strongly depends on what you want - sha256 is a cryptographic hash function that is relatively slow to calculate, takes bytes-input and produces bytes output. good non-cryptographic hashes are fast to compute, have an even distribution of resulting values and not too many collisions.

Comment: What do you intend to do with this hash? How large is the domain of the input integers, what's a typical size of an input sequence, and how large should the range of the output be? How important is collision avoidance? Your needs may be satisfied by a variant of [format-preserving encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption), either a full cryptographic-strength implementation, or a faster, simpler version.

Comment: @PM2Ring, I want to use a single decimal num to identify a sequence of numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to hash a number sequence you can do

```
def my_hash(*args):
    return hash(args)
```

which returns the [hash](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hash) (for the current run of the program) of the args-tuple (`hash` is fast and well tested for builtin-types) - but this is still most often a large number.

For getting a smaller value you can take the modulo like

```
def my_hash(*args):
    return hash(args)%10 # or whatever number you like
```

Actually you could also use

```
def my_hash(*args):
    return sum(args)%10 # or whatever number you like
```

which doesnt change between runs of the program but `sum` does not distribute the results evenly at all.

**Warning: These are not cryptographical hashes**

Comment: hi, @janbrohl, does python2 have a similar function like `hash`?

Comment: Yes ([same name](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hash)) - It possibly returns different values but it is essentially the same

Comment: Most stuff didnt change (much) from Python 2.7 to 3.x and *simple* programs work on both requiring ony minimal changes (or none at all)

Comment: I marked the answer as accepted, but for the second question, the output will be in range 0 to 9 if I use `%10` and thus cause collisions. I will use a dict to map every hash values to my desire numbers.

Comment: for less collisions ditribute the hashes over a larger range of numbers by using bigger values for `%`-ing than `10`